# ASP.NET 5 Ignoring Header Accept xml

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core-mvc

NET 5 MVC Project (RC1) and I'm trying to output Xml from the controller and it doesn't work even though I've added the dependency on the project.json file

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Formatters.Xml": "6.0.0-rc1-final"
```

I have adde the formatter to the Startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

And I have this in the header

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/xml
```

I am sending Json but expect Xml in the response, but I keep getting Json.

Any clues what I might be missing?

BTW the controller is returning an Xsd.exe generated object

thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found that if in your class you have this attribute on a property

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute(typeof(string))]
```

it will end up forcing the whole class to be returned as JSON. pretty odd